# Python - Create a new sublist between two elements in an ordered list

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice, circular-list

Given two elements in an ordered list, I want to make a  new list consisting of everything between (and including) those elements.
The problem comes if the second point comes before the first point in the list. 
right is my existing sorted list of objects. rt is the beginning boundary and rb is the end boundary.
`new_right = right[right.index(rt): right.index(rb) + 1]`

This snippet works except in the case

`right = [a, rb, c, rt, d, e]`

where I get `[rt, d, e]` instead of the wrapped `[rt, d, e, a, rb]`

Is there a way to do this without creating a complicated method? Some other people's problems were solved by list comprehension. Looking into it, I was able to come up with

```
begin = right.index(rt)
end = right.index(rb)
if end > begin:
    new_right = right[begin: end + 1]
else:
    new_right = [right[i % r_len] for i in range(begin, r_len + end + 1)]
```

Which looks pretty ugly to me, but it seems to hold up to my tests. 
Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
There were two working solutions to this.

```
rbegin = right.index(rt)
rend = right.index(rb)
if rend >= rbegin:
    new_right = right[rbegin: rend + 1]
else:
    new_right = [right[i % r_len] for i in range(rbegin, r_len + rend + 1)]
```

Which is obscenely complicated compared to:

```
if rend > rbegin:
    new_right = right[rbegin: rend + 1]
else:
    new_right = right[rbegin:] + right[:rend + 1]
```

Comment: Your use of "between" to mean "from begin to end, wrapping around to the start if necessary" seems to be confusing those reading your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would simply flipping the slice match your tests like so:

```
begin = right.index(rt)
end = right.index(rb)
if end > begin:
    new_right = right[begin: end + 1]
else:
    new_right = right[end: begin + 1]
```

Comment: This seems to be one index off. Took me a while to test it.

Comment: You can correct that by adding or subtracting one accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
new_right = right[begin: end + 1] if end > begin else right[begin:] + right[:end + 1]
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I'll post my monstrosity as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the trailing and leading slices instead of using a comprehension.  Using your code structure:

```
begin = right.index(rt)
end = right.index(rb)
if end > begin:
    new_right = right[begin: end + 1]
else:
    new_right = right[begin:] + right[:end + 1]
```

Comment: This is missing the plus one in ``` right[:end + 1]``` to include that last element. But otherwise, yes.